# Vlookup of text values

Tags: excel

I wanted to know if there was a way to use a vlookup on text values. Normally, I have been converting my text values to a number and then doing a vlookup, but this can be time consuming. For example, if i have a column of numbers (formatted as text) like 100-4333-239 I have been removing the "-" and converting to a number and then doing a vlookup. Is there a way to look up text without all the converting?

Thank you.

Comment: yes, `VLOOKUP` works on any data type as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you can vlookup text values. If you are using the reference `100-4333-239` and one of the indexes in the table-array is `100-4333-239`, it will work. You can easily try it out.

Comment: The common problem with vlookup and text data is Excel needs to think the reference and lookup list are of the same type.  Especially when dealing with data that is just numbers, Excel gets confused sometimes.  Look for the green triangles in the upper left of your cells.  You need both data locations to either have them, or not have them.  If it is mismatched vlookup will fail.

Answer (score 4):

The last argument determines whether `VLOOKUP` should find "approximate" matches as well (which is, in my opinion, a bad description -- passing `TRUE` there or leaving the argument out seems to tell Excel that the table is sorted). In practice, this means that you should pass `FALSE` when searching for text:

```
=VLOOKUP("100-4333-239";B2:C10;2;FALSE)
```

should give you "THERESULT" if you have "100-4333-239" in cell B4 and "THERESULT" in cell C4:

```
      A         B          C
1  |     |            |         |
2  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
3  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
4  |     |100-4333-239|THERESULT|
5  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
6  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
7  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
8  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
9  |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
10 |     |999-9999-999|   XX    |
11 |     |            |         |
```

Comment: The last argument for VLOOKUP is not whether it is sorted, but if you use true you will get unpredictable results if the table is not sorted. I know myself, I have never had a need to use TRUE in any of the many many vlookups I have typed over the years.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: handy read for folks that are new to vlookup.http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2637-Six-Reasons-Why-Your-VLOOKUP-or-HLOOKUP-Formula-Does-Not-Work.html